# Reading name and number from file and modifying

Tags: c

I have a text file with the stats of some players which should be formatted this:

```
name(can be multiple spaces/names) score
```

For example:

```
John Andrew Brown 234
Mike Smith 13
```

I need a function which recieves as paramter a char array with the name of a person and find in the file that person and add 1 to its score. So, if the function recieves "Mike Smith", the file will be modified like this:

```
John Andrew Brown 234
Mike Smith 14
```

I don't know how to read the name and the number separately. If I read with fgets, the whole line will be read and I will need to rewind or go at the start of the line with fseek and ftell. Is there a way to jump directly at the number and modify it?

Comment: It can not be rewritten by simply fseek there is a possibility to carry because it is not a fixed size record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First about modifying text files with variable-length records (like you have), there are two "standard" or "normal" ways of doing that:

1. You can load the whole file into memory one way or another (for example into a list of structures) and modify the in-memory copy, and then overwrite the complete file with the (now modified) in-memory data.
2. Since each record in your file is a single line, you can read one line at a time, and write it out to a new *temporary* file, and if you read the record (or records) you want to modify you do the modification before you write it out to the temporary file. Once done you close the original file and rename the temporary file to the original file.

---

As for how to extract the name and number separately, there are a couple of ways to do this. One possibility is to use [`fscanf` (or `sscanf`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) using the `"%["` format, but it's very hard to get right.

Another way is to read the whole line, trim away trailing white-space, and then look for the *last* space, and split the line into two sub-strings in that location. The first will be the name and the second will be the number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess that the 2nd option will do it. But what if I have very large files (not my case)? The 2 methods won't be that viable.

Comment: @rptoma If you start to get a lot of data to store, then you should probably look into some other type of storage for the data, like some kind of database.